# Ask Push Notification Permission after launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I want to ask for push notifications permission after the user has registered. Then I want to check if they're turned on every time the user launches the app, and if not, trigger the apparition of a menu that asks for the permission because it is required to get access to the app. Here's my code in the appDelegate so far :

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, _ in
            guard success else {
                return
            }
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        messaging.token { token, _ in
            guard let token = token else {
                return
            }
            print("Token : \(token)")
        }
    }
```

Now this works, but I don't know how to check and ask for it later. Will it not cause issue if it's not in the appdelegate ? What do I do with the `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` ?

Comment: You can register for remote notifications at any time. Permission is not required to register and get the push token. However, push notifications are not shown unless you have asked for and received permission.  So you can leave your remote notification registration in the app delegate and ask for notification permissions elsewhere